# MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line

Tags: android, json, gson

I've got a JSON string and this is just a part of it:

```
"geoLocation":{
    "latitude": 46.05570,
    "longitude": 14.50705,
},
```

I've also got a custom class and I'm trying to use GSON to get array of objects from this JSON like this:

```
locationList = gson.fromJson(responseString, Location[].class);
```

But the app crashes on the line above and this is the Logcat:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 15 column 6 path $[0].geoLocation.
```

This is how the part of the class with geoLocation variables looks like:

```
public class Location {
    ...
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    ...
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting the crash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
"geoLocation":{
    "latitude": 46.05570,
    "longitude": 14.50705,
}
```

comma after longitude is invalid. Remove it.